# While running some test code in Fortran, I received an error "f951: Fatal Error: Cannot open file 'hello.f90' compilation terminated

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am new to Fortran and I am trying to execute some test code, printing hello world using the following program -

```
program hello
    implicit none
    print *, 'Hello, World!'
    
end program hello
```

I am using MacOS Ventura 13.1 and I am using VS Code as a text editor, and have installed homebrew using the command `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"` in the terminal and installed gfortran using `brew install gfortran`. I am unsure what the problem is but browsing through other questions perhaps there is a path error of some kind? I am not sure what this means. Any help would be gladly appreciated!

Comment: For whatever reason it can't find the file hello.f90. Please *edit the question* to tell us a) the exact command you are using which results in this error b) the output of `ls` at the command prompt just before or after you issue the gfortran command. Oh, and just checking my favourite stupidity, you have remembered to save the file from the editor?

Comment: Hi Ian, so the command I am using in the terminal is `gfortran hello.f90 -o hello` and the output of `ls` is just hello.f90

Comment: @IanBush another new change is that when I try to re run the command `gfortran hello.f90 -o hello` a terminal in VSCode, I now get the error - `ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd' for architecture arm64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`.

Comment: Please *edit the question* to include these details. But OK, the basics seemed satisfied, to go further you need someone who knows Macs - I don't (but we have had similar looking questions here before)

Comment: A mix macOS/VSCode/gfortran is likely to raise some issues... Try compiling not from a VSCode terminal, but from a standard macOS terminal.